# Struggling to run command in Fargate container - executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: dockerfile, aws-fargate

A bit of an odd one here, and other similar answers I've found haven't helped.

I've built a custom image using Alpine, and it has the following installed:

aws cli
terraform
python

If I run the container locally with 'docker run -it' it brings me to an interactive shell as expected, and regardless of where I am in the file system I'm able to run commands such as:

terraform --version
aws --version

and get the correct output. However, when I try do to the same in Fargate (by setting the 'entry point' or 'docker command' in the Task Definition the logs show it's complaining about the executable file not found in $PATH.

I'm fairly noobish to Docker and Fargate, but I've tried changing the 'terraform --version' command between 'entry point' and 'command' in the Fargate task definition. Both result in the same error.

Running 'echo #PATH' in the locally running version I get this:

/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/aws-cli/bin

but trying that in the Fargate container gives the error about executable file not found in $PATH

Other info:
find / -name 'terraform' -type f
/bin/terraform
/usr/bin/terraform

I managed to get limited success changing the command to 'ls' and it provided the following output:

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   2to3

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   2to3-3.9

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   idle

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   idle3

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   idle3.9

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   pip

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   pip3

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   pip3.9

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   pydoc

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   pydoc3

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   pydoc3.9

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   python

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   python-config

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   python3

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   python3-config

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   python3.9

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   python3.9-config

2023-05-02T15:13:23.770+01:00   wheel

Here the working directory was also changed to '"/usr/local/bin"', but keeping that change and trying the other commands result in the same error.

Here's the dockerfile (sorry for the length):

```
FROM python:3.9.16-alpine3.17 AS builder
ARG AWSCLI_VERSION=2.11.4

# Build AWSCLI V2 from source to use in final docker image
ADD https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-${AWSCLI_VERSION}.tar.gz /
RUN tar -xzf awscli-${AWSCLI_VERSION}.tar.gz
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    curl \
    make \
    cmake \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    libc-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    && cd awscli-${AWSCLI_VERSION} \
    && ./configure --prefix=/opt/aws-cli/ --with-download-deps \
    && make \
    && make install

# Build final image and install Python & Terraform
FROM alpine:3.17.3

# Python build/install
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux; apk add --no-cache ca-certificates tzdata ; # buildkit
ENV GPG_KEY=<KEY REMOVED FOR DISPLAY>
ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.16
RUN <REMOVED TO KEEP LENGTH SHORT>
ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=22.0.4
ENV PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=58.1.0
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/d5cb0afaf23b8520f1bbcfed521017b4a95f5c01/public/get-pip.py
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=394be00f13fa1b9aaa47e911bdb59a09c3b2986472130f30aa0bfaf7f3980637
RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux; wget -O get-pip.py "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL"; echo "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 *get-pip.py" | sha256sum -c -; export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1; python get-pip.py --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --no-compile "pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" "setuptools==$PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION" ; rm -f get-pip.py; pip --version # buildkit

# Copy compiled AWSCLI V2 from builder images
RUN apk --no-cache add groff
COPY --from=builder /opt/aws-cli/ /opt/aws-cli/
ENV TF_VERSION=1.1.9

# Install Terraform
ADD https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TF_VERSION}/terraform_${TF_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip /
RUN unzip terraform_${TF_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip
RUN cp terraform /bin/
RUN mv terraform /usr/bin/

# Set path
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/aws-cli/bin"
```

Comment: "complaining about the executable file not found in $PATH" you need to include the specific error exactly.  "I try do to the same in Fargate (by setting the 'entry point' or 'docker command' " we will need to see how you did that too.

Comment: Regarding the Fargate part - I just use the console to run a new task, and in the options I select the 'container overrides' then in the 'Command override' section I enter 'terraform --version' so that it runs that command at runtime.

Comment: And the error in the event log is:  runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "terraform --version": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: looks like it's trying to run the whole thing with spaces.  Perhaps `terraform` should be the ENTRYPOINT and `--version` should be the CMD?

Comment: Thanks for helping! I managed to figure it out and have posted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Fargate expects the command option to be separated by a comma, not a space. So the command under 'Entry Point' should be 'terraform,--version'